# Automatic cast in scala

Tags: scala

I am accessing elements from a list which can belong to two different classes. For example:

```
sealed abstract class A
case class B extends A
case class C extends A
...
var l = List[A] // every element in this list belongs either to B or C
```

When popping out elements from this list, I'd like to understand whether they belong to B or C and act accordingly. I would like to avoid to create a big match-case, such as:

```
elem = l.head
elem match {
    case v:B => //code for B
    case v:C => //code for C
}
```

I would like to do something like the following:

```
val elem = l.head
var k = elem match {
      case v:B => v.asInstanceOf[B]
      case v:C => v.asInstanceOf[C]
  }
```

Comment: What do you want the static type of `v` to be?

Comment: if elem belongs to B then B, otherwise C

Comment: Do you know the number of elements in `List` during compile time?

Comment: But the static type can't be determined by information you only have at runtime.

Comment: To emphasize @TravisBrown's point, if `B` has a method, `foo`, and `A` does not have that method, do you expect to be able to call `k.foo`?

Comment: Oh, no. I only use the common fields.

Comment: Why do you want to distinguish `B` from `C` then? If you use common methods you can simply have normal object-oriented polymorphism.

Comment: Yeah, what @Kolmar said.  Just do `val k: A = l.head` (you don't need the type annotation, I just put it here for clarity)

Answer (score 1):

The only chance except the runtime check with the `case` that you want to avoid would be to use a `HList`as for example the `shapeless`-library provides.

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

This would allow you you to keep the type information that otherwise would be lost.

Comment: Remember that this is possible only if you know the number of elements and their type during compile time, which is often not the case